# Double stops in ABRSM Grade 7 violin

Tags: violin, abrsm

I am going to do ABRSM Grade 7 violin. Under scales and arpeggios I have to play double-stop scales in sixths, in G and Bb majors.

In a book I found out that when I am asked to play double stops in sixths in G I have to start with G & Eb. I am confused with the Eb as there's no Eb in G major scale.

Is this Eb a mistake?

If not why it is not Eb instead of E?

How to find out notes for other double stops?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These double-stop sixths will have the tonic of the scale up top, with the third of the scale on the bottom.

In the book you found, those double-stop sixths are actually in the key of E♭ major; E♭ (scale-degree 1) is on top and G (scale-degree 3) is on the bottom.

If you want sixths in the key of G major, you'll have G on top and B on the bottom. The scale will be:

```
    G  A  B  C  D  E  F♯ G
    B  C  D  E  F♯ G  A  B
```

In the key of B♭ you will have:

```
    B♭ C  D  E♭ F  G  A  B♭
    D  E♭ F  G  A  B♭ C  D
```

Comment: So when I am playing in G, I have to start with G on 3rd string and B on 4th string?

Comment: Just been on ABRSM website, and yes, it's G also Bb (maj) in 6ths. So I don't know why Eb should be there, except in the Bb scale. There is a pdf available, but it won't download for me.

Comment: @LasithaYapa I actually don't play violin, so I unfortunately can't help you. Hopefully someone else can!

Comment: @LasithaYapa - I hope you got this resolved last spring.  Just in case: "So when I am playing in G, I have to start with G on 3rd string and B on 4th string?"  Yes. // Do you have a teacher who can guide you with these things?